# jFileUpload does't support chinese file names

Tags: jquery, file-upload

I am using jFileUpload control and it worked great till now..

But now i am facing problem in uploading the files having chinese name like abc教程.mp4

I tried the following..

```
<param name ="resources" value="i18n"/>
```

as well...

The control shows the file name in jFileUpload Progress Message perfectly..

But it shows abc??.mp4 in java consol..

Please help me out here..
Is there anything i am missing?
is there anything i need to do with IIS..since i am running my application on IIS Server..?

Comment: You may need to make sure your website is using utf-8, including scripts, IIS/apache settings, asp/php/etc settings?

Comment: How can i check that ..?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I'm a apache user, but you could try this in html:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
```

or this in http header (set it in IIS settings or use some kind of server side script functions)

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

Comment: thanks agou for your reply...i have tried these both ways but could be successful..!

Answer (score 0):

just Need to add this param in jFileUpload

```
<param name="encoding" value="UTF8">
```

..it solved perfectly..!